# D3 line chart mouse event issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below d3 code the line d3.mouse(this) is throwing exception as source event is null.when more then one chart is drawn on the same page using different div container.can somebody help me identify what went wrong?

```
function createLineChart(divId, chartData) {
    jq.getScript('js/lib/d3.v3.min.js', function() {

            var response = jq.parseJSON(chartData);
            console.log(response);
            var datum = response.chartData;
            divElement = jq('$'+divId).empty();
            var fullHeight = divElement.height();
            var fullWidth = divElement.width();

            if(fullWidth < 50 ){ fullWidth = 400; }
            if(fullHeight < 50 ){ fullHeight = 385; }

            divElement.append(jq("<div id='chartHolder' class='chartHolder'/>" ));

            var divToDraw = d3.select(divElement.get(0)).select("div");

            var largeGraph = (datum.length > 10);
            var secondLine = response.secondLine;
            var data = datum;

            var main_margin, mini_margin,  main_width, main_height, mini_height;

            if(largeGraph) {
                main_margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 50},
                mini_margin = {top: fullHeight-70, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50},
                main_width = fullWidth - main_margin.left - main_margin.right,
                main_height = fullHeight - main_margin.top - main_margin.bottom,
                mini_height = fullHeight - mini_margin.top - mini_margin.bottom;
            } else {
                main_margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: response.xWidth + 25, left: 50},
                mini_margin = {top: fullHeight-30 , right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 0},
                main_width = fullWidth - main_margin.left - main_margin.right,
                main_height = fullHeight - main_margin.top - main_margin.bottom,
                mini_height = fullHeight - mini_margin.top - mini_margin.bottom;
            }

            var barLabels = data.map(function(datum){
                return datum.xData;
            });

            var main_x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, main_width], 1),
                mini_x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, main_width], 1);

            var main_y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([main_height, 0]),
                mini_y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([mini_height, 0]);

            var main_y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([main_height, 0]),
                mini_y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([mini_height, 0]);

            var main_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(main_x)
                .orient("bottom");

            var main_yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(main_y0)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

            var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                .x(mini_x)
                .on("brush", brush);

            var main_line0 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return main_x(d.xData); })
                .y(function(d) { return main_y0(d.yData); });

            var main_line1 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return main_x(d.xData); })
                .y(function(d) { return main_y0(d.yData2); });

            var mini_line0 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return mini_x(d.xData); })
                .y(function(d) { return mini_y0(d.yData); });

            var mini_line1 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return mini_x(d.xData); })
                .y(function(d) { return mini_y0(d.yData2); });

            var maxValue = d3.max(data,function(d){ return d.yData; });
            main_x.domain(barLabels);
            mini_x.domain(main_x.domain());

            if(secondLine) {
                var maxValue_y1 = d3.max(data,function(d){ return d.yData2; });
                if(maxValue > maxValue_y1)
                    main_y0.domain([0, maxValue]);
                else
                    main_y0.domain([0, maxValue_y1]);
                main_y1.domain([0, maxValue_y1]);
                mini_y1.domain(main_y1.domain());
            } else  {
                main_y0.domain([0, maxValue]);
            }
            mini_y0.domain(main_y0.domain());

            if(data.length > 11)
                main_xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) { return ''; });

            //preparing text/header for chart
            var title_text = function(){
                if(secondLine) {
                    return response.yName + ' & ' + response.yName2 + ' by ' + response.xName;
                } else {
                    return response.yName + ' by ' + response.xName;
                }
            };
            if(response.filterColumn != null && response.from != null) {
                title_text += ' where '
                            + response.filterColumn + ' between ' + response.from
                            + ' and ' + response.to;
            }

            var svg = divToDraw.append("svg")
                        .attr("width", main_width + main_margin.left + main_margin.right)
                        .attr("height", main_height + main_margin.top + main_margin.bottom);

            svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
                    .attr("id", "clip")
                .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", main_width)
                    .attr("height", main_height);

            var main = svg.append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + main_margin.left + "," + main_margin.top + ")");

            var mini = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + mini_margin.left + "," + mini_margin.top + ")");

            main.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                .attr("class", "line line0")
                .attr("d", main_line0);

            main.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x linechart_axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + main_height + ")")
                .call(main_xAxis)
                .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width/2 + ",0)")
                    .attr("dy",response.xWidth + 10)
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(response.xName);

            var yLabel = main.append("g") 
                .attr("transform", "translate(-43,"+(main_height/2)+")")
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle");

            yLabel.text(response.yName);

            if(secondLine) {
                yLabel.text(response.yName + " & " + response.yName2);
                main.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                .attr("class", "line line1")
                .attr("d", main_line1);
            }

            main.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y linechart_axis axisLeft")
                .call(main_yAxisLeft);

            if(largeGraph) {
                mini.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x linechart_axis mini_axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + mini_height + ")")
                .call(main_xAxis);

                mini.append("path")
                .datum(datum)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", mini_line0);

                if(secondLine) {      
                mini.append("path")
                .datum(datum)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", mini_line1);
                }

                mini.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x brush")
                .call(brush)
                .selectAll("rect")
                .attr("y", -6)
                .attr("height", mini_height + 7);
            }

            var focus = main.append("g")
                .attr("class", "focus")
                .style("display", "none");

            // Display on the x Axis
            focus.append("line")
                .attr("class", "x")
                .attr("y1", main_y0(0) - 6)
                .attr("y2", main_y0(0) + 6)

            // Display for first line
            focus.append("line")
                .attr("class", "y0")
                .attr("x1", main_width - 6) // nach links
                .attr("x2", main_width + 6); // nach rechts

            focus.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "y0")
                .attr("r", 4);

            focus.append("text")
                .attr("class", "y0")  
                .attr("dy", "-1em"); 

            if(secondLine) {
                //Display for second line
                focus.append("line")
                    .attr("class", "y1")
                    .attr("x1", main_width - 6)
                    .attr("x2", main_width + 6);

                focus.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "y1")
                    .attr("r", 4);

                focus.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "y1")  
                    .attr("dy", "-1em");
            }


            main.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "overlay")
                .attr("width", main_width)
                .attr("height", main_height)
                .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
                .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
                .on("mousemove", mousemove);

            function mousemove() {

                console.log(this);

                var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
                var leftEdges = main_x.range();
                var width = main_x.rangeBand();
                var j;
                for(j=0; xPos > (leftEdges[j] + width); j++) {}
                d = data[j];
                if(d === undefined) {
                    return;
                }

                focus.select("circle.y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.xData) + "," + main_y0(d.yData) + ")");
                focus.select("text.y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.xData) + "," + main_y0(d.yData) + ")").text(d.yData);
                focus.select(".x").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.xData) + ",0)");
                focus.select(".y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width * -1 + ", " + main_y0(d.yData) + ")").attr("x2", main_width + main_x(d.xData));
                if(secondLine) {
                    focus.select("circle.y1").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.xData) + "," + main_y0(d.yData2) + ")");
                    focus.select("text.y1").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.xData) + "," + main_y0(d.yData2) + ")").text(d.yData2);
                    focus.select(".y1").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width * -1 + ", " + main_y0(d.yData2) + ")").attr("x2", main_width + main_x(d.xData));
                }
            }

            //inserting line breaks
            var insertLinebreaks = function (d) {
                var el = d3.select(this);
                var words = d.split(' ');
                el.text('');

                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
                    if (i > 0)
                        tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
                }
            };

            function brush() {
            //Creating new subset of data to draw the graph
            var s = d3.event.target.extent();
            var newArray = [];
            var newData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < barLabels.length; i++) {
            if(s[0] <= (d = mini_x(barLabels[i])) && d <= s[1]) {
                newArray.push(barLabels[i]);
                newData.push(datum[i]);
            }
            }
            main_x.domain(brush.empty() ? mini_x.domain() : newArray);

            // Checking when no nodes are selected
            if(newData.length > 0 ) {
                main.datum(newData);
                data = newData;
            } else {
                main.datum(datum);
                data = datum;
            }   
            main.select(".line0").attr("d", main_line0);

            if(secondLine) {
                main.select(".line1").attr("d", main_line1);
            }

            main.select(".x.linechart_axis").call(main_xAxis);
            if(data.length < 11)
                main.selectAll('g.x.linechart_axis g text').each(insertLinebreaks);
            }

            if(data.length < 11)
                main.selectAll('g.x.linechart_axis g text').each(insertLinebreaks);

            //Legend
            var legendData = new Array();
            legendData.push(response.yName)

            if(secondLine) {
                legendData.push(response.yName2)
            }

            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data(legendData)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {return "translate(0," + ((i * 20) + 3)  + ")"; }); //Additional 3 for top-margin

            legend.append("line")
              .attr("x2", fullWidth - 18 - 10) // 10 for padding
              .attr("x1", fullWidth - 34 - 10)
              .attr("y1", 10)
              .attr("y2", 10)
              .style("stroke", function(d,i){ if(i==0) return "steelblue"; else return "indianred"; });

            legend.append("text")
              .attr("x", fullWidth - 40 - 10) // 10 for padding
              .attr("y", 9)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please?